# Why actionscript3 method for event not recognises properties like button.X,Y, etc

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

- I have a constructor function
- There i write properties like button.X=20 etc. and they work
- But I created another function in the same class in which i used properties like button.X=PosX etc. and they dont work

Errors Are :

```
1120: Access of undefined property button.var posX:Number = (stage.stageWidth / 2) - (button.width / 2);
1120: Access of undefined property button.posY:Number = (stage.stageHeight / 2) - (button.height / 2);
1120: Access of undefined property button.button.x = posX;
1120: Access of undefined property button.button.y = posY;
```

The Code of this Document class is :

```
package
{
   import flash.text.TextField;
   import flash.display.Sprite;
   import flash.display.BitmapData;
   import flash.display.Bitmap;
   import flash.display.SimpleButton;
   import flash.display.MovieClip;
   import flash.events.Event;
   import flash.events.MouseEvent;
   import flash.display.DisplayObject;
   import flash.events.Event;
   import flash.display.StageScaleMode;
   import flash.display.StageAlign;

   public class main extends MovieClip
    {
function main()
{
    stage.addEventListener(Event.RESIZE, resizeHandler);
    stage.dispatchEvent(new Event(Event.RESIZE));
    stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
    stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;

    var button:graphic = new graphic();
    addChild(button);
    var field:type = new type();
    addChild(field);
}
function resizeHandler(event:Event):void
{
    var posX:Number = (stage.stageWidth / 2) - (button.width / 2);
    var posY:Number = (stage.stageHeight / 2) - (button.height / 2);

    button.x = posX;
    button.y = posY;
}
    }
}
```

I am new to programming so please Explain a little more that what is the error and what is the solution and Is it right to have many functions like that ?

Comment: The answers are bit technical if you are a beginner... basically it's a scope problem. When you create a var in a function it's only available in the code inside the function. When you create the var in a class it's available to all the class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is `button` is a local variable inside `main` and is not available to `resize`.  You either have to change button to be a class field or change `resize` to close over button.

To use a class field (preferred):

```
public class main extends MovieClip
{
    private var _button:Graphic;

    function main()
    {
        stage.addEventListener(Event.RESIZE, resizeHandler);
        stage.dispatchEvent(new Event(Event.RESIZE));
        stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
        stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;

        _button= new graphic();
        addChild(_button);
        var field:type = new type();
        addChild(field);
    }
    function resizeHandler(event:Event):void
    {
        var posX:Number = (stage.stageWidth / 2) - (_button.width / 2);
        var posY:Number = (stage.stageHeight / 2) - (_button.height / 2);

        _button.x = posX;
        _button.y = posY;
    }
}
```

To close over button:

```
public class main extends MovieClip
{

    function main()
    {
        stage.addEventListener(Event.RESIZE, resizeHandler);
        stage.dispatchEvent(new Event(Event.RESIZE));
        stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
        stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;

        var button:graphic = new graphic();
        addChild(button);
        var field:type = new type();
        addChild(field);

        function resizeHandler(event:Event):void
        {
            var posX:Number = (stage.stageWidth / 2) - (button.width / 2);
            var posY:Number = (stage.stageHeight / 2) - (button.height / 2);

            button.x = posX;
            button.y = posY;
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is the **scope** of the `button` variable.

Since you declare the variable within the `main` function, it is only recognized within the scope of that function. The `resizeHandler` function doesn't know anything about a variable named 'button'.

To make the variable available to both functions, you can change its scope to be recognized in the entire `main` class. Just move the variable declaration outside of the `main` function (but still contained within the class).